# Operation Queue with paused consumer in .NET

Tags: c#, queue

I need to implement in C# 4.0 a logic where an operation might be either executed immediately or put in a Queue waiting that a certain network service becomes available.

What is the best approach to implement such an operation? Is it having a thread-safe queue of Function and a polling consumer that consumes these operations only when the resource is available?

Is there any library or example for implementing similar features?

Answer (score 1):

We can have producer consumer approach with plenty of implementation out. In addition,  .NET `Concurrent` namespace also have `BlockingCollection<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. However, it seems the challenge is not to implement producer consumer pattern but to wait in the `Queue` until some resource is available (network service in your case). This is more of a *non-deterministic situation*, where you have no idea when the resource will be ready to consume. This challenge can be addressed through having a queue with persistence. Eg: `Microsoft's Message Queue (MSMQ)` with private/public queue.